# apt is trying to remove linux-image-3.8.11

Tags: linux, apt

I am running a Crouton on my chromebook. Every time I try to install a package, `apt` tries to remove `linux-image-3.8.11`. It initially tried to install it while installing a package, (the installer said it was already there and quit). My question is whether there is a way to tell `apt` to pretend that package is not installed so I can go on using my computer without it trying to uninstall it every time I install a package.

I just tried holding the package, but now I get `E: Can't find a source to download version '20160402' of 'linux-image-3.8.11:amd64'`

`apt` thinks the package is neither installed or uninstalled, and as this is in a userland running in a chroot with no kernel access, I can't really modify the kernel. What I mainly want to do is fool apt into thinking the package is installed. E.G. make the install and/or uninstall scripts do nothing and report success. That would be fine for me.

EDIT: here is the contents of the `/var/lib/dpkg/status` file regarding that package

```
Package: linux-image-3.8.11
Status: deinstall ok half-installed
Priority: optional
Section: kernel
Installed-Size: 19919
Maintainer: Unknown Kernel Package Maintainer <unknown@unconfigured.in.etc.kernel-pkg.conf>
Architecture: amd64
Source: linux-source-3.8.11
Version: 20160402
Config-Version: 20160402
Provides: linux-image, linux-image-3.8
Depends: coreutils (>= 5.96), initramfs-tools | linux-initramfs-tool
Pre-Depends: debconf (>= 0.2.17) | debconf-2.0
Suggests: fdutils, linux-doc-3.8.11 | linux-source-3.8.11, ksymoops, linux-image-3.8.11-dbg
Description: Linux kernel binary image for version 3.8.11
 This package contains the Linux kernel image for version
 3.8.11.
 .
 It also contains the corresponding System.map file, and the modules
 built by the packager.  It also contains scripts that try to ensure
 that the system is not left in a unbootable state after an update.
 .
 Kernel image packages are generally produced using kernel-package,
 and it is suggested that you install that package if you wish to
 create a custom kernel from the sources. Please look at kernel-img.conf(5),
 and /usr/share/doc/kernel-package/README.gz  from the package kernel-package
 for details on how to tailor the  installation of this or any other kernel
 image package
```

Do I just change deinstall ok half-installed to something else?

Comment: At the moment, I'm not really interested in fixing the underlying cause. What I would like is for `apt` to just work without throwing errors over kernels.

Comment: could you post full output when you install a package ?

Comment: `(Ubuntu)rumpaar1@localhost:~$ sudo apt-get install cowsay
[sudo] password for rumpaar1: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  filters
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  cowsay
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 60 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
E: Can't find a source to download version '20160402' of 'linux-image-3.8.11:amd64'
(Ubuntu)rumpaar1@localhost:~$`

Comment: could you please check `/var/lib/dpkg/status` and post it. and Don't extend conversation here, if anybody asks you for input, output or any info, [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/288083/edit) you own post, so that everybody knows it what's causing you problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just removed the package info for `linux-image-3.8.11` from `/var/lib/dpkg/status` and that has seemed to work. I was able to install `cowsay` so the problem seems to have been fixed. Thanks.

Comment: I should get the credit for this answer ;) anyways that's good.

Comment: Yeah, I really just needed pointing in the direction of where and how dpkg stores what packages it has installed or half-installed in this case. Anyway, if you want credit, post a new answer outlining how to do what I already did and I'll mark it as an answer for you :)

Comment: No that's fine.. I am glad it helped you to fix your problem. +1 for you.